# Use of "When" in present vs "whenever"

Tags: conditional-constructions

I know that *if* and *when* are conditionals and you don't say "If I will" OR "when I will".You use present to talk about ***future***:

> ***When I become a millionaire***, I will go to Paris

But what if I actually want to talk about the present

> *When I get money, I spend it instantly*
>    Or
>   *When I get tired, I become very ill-tempered*

Are the above sentences correct? Do I have to use "whenever" in such scenario?

Comment: What makes you think that "when" is conditional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ***whenever*** in OP's examples *always* strongly implies that the "conditional / hypothetical" scenario referred to *has happened more than once in the past* (and could be expected to happen *again* in the future).

You *can* use plain ***when*** in the above context, but this version could also be used to refer to *some expected future situation* that's never happened before.

Using real-world pragmatics (which actual situations are more *likely?*) it would be easy to simply say that only ***when*** works with the "millionaire" example. But obviously there are at least *some* people (Donald Trump comes to mind) who have become millionaires more than once in their lives.

---

Note that *to some extent*, using a future tense after ***when*** implies the "hasn't happened before" context, so given the alternatives...

> 1: *When I get money, I spend it instantly*
>    2: *When I get money, I **will** spend it instantly*

...we naturally tend to interpret #1 as having the ***whenever*** sense (past and future), and #2 as referring to a single anticipated *future* event. But be aware that *sometimes*, perfectly competent native speakers will use #2 even if they intend the ***whenever*** sense (it's really just a relatively uncommon *stylistic* choice).

Comment: So "when" in "when i get money ,i spend it instantly" is as correct as "whenever" ,even in formal writing ?

Comment: Absolutely - no native speaker would ever dispute that. The area where *some* native speakers might disagree is in contexts where it's not contextually obvious whether the "trigger event" is a single [future] event, or something that might have already occurred repeatedly, ***and*** speaker uses an explicit future tense to refer to the reaction to that trigger. Such as ***When** he wins the jackpot at the local bingo hall, he **will** buy drinks all round*. Some people will say that can *only* refer to a one-off future event, but other (perfectly competent) native speakers may disagree.

Answer (score 2):

> *When(ever) I get money, I spend it instantly*.
>
> *When(ever) I get tired, I become very ill-tempered*.

The -*ever* forms are preferable. They mark the phrases as being non-referential: there is no reference to any particular time.

Your examples can be glossed as "Every time I get money I spend it / "Every time I get tired, I become very ill-tempered.

The "every" interpretation expresses multiple situations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are correct. See the example sentence under definition 1c of [when](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when). Even if used as a conditional, you can use the present tense (see defintion 2, same link). Rather than focusing on "future or present", you should decide by whether the action is likely to happen repeatedly.

You are likely to receive money every month, and you are likely to get tired all the time, so you use the present tense in those sentences. However, you are unlikely to become a millionaire repeatedly, hence becoming a millionaire is a very specific and unique event for you (in the future apparently), and the future tense is the better choice.